# How can I pass a value from a function to any component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I want to pass a value which I am receiving in a function like this:

```js
const ViewDetails = item => () => {
   console.log(item);
   toggleModal();
}
```

I want to pass the item to Modal component **like open,onclose** which is called in the Main function:

```js
return (
   <Layout title="Dashboard" className="container-fluid">
      {<Modal open={modalStatus} onClose={() => setModalStatus(false)} />}
      <div className="row">
         <div className="col-sm-3">
            <UserLinks />
         </div>
         <div className="col-sm-9">
             <UserInfo />
             {orders ? <PurchaseHistory /> : ""}
         </div>
      </div>
   </Layout>
)
```

I am expecting to have something like this:
`{<Modal open={modalStatus} onClose={() => setModalStatus(false)} ***item={item}***/>}`
so that I can use the values inside item in Modal component.

Comment: Please add ViewDetails() part that is used.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Could you please explain further?

Comment: So, I am receiving the **item** from another component in the viewDetails function. After I click on the viewDetails it changes the state value which lets the modal to appear. And whenever the viewDetails function is triggered I want to pass the item variable to the Modal component so that I can use it in modal.

Comment: I mean, need to see that function where it is called, the code is incomplete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to take state for this item. When viewDetails function triggered from inside this function you can set this state with this item afte can be pass this state as a props any component

Comment: Please provide a solution with the source code provided how did you come up with the solution, this will be helpful for members in the future when they come up with a similar problem and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import React from "react";

function Eexample() {
  const ViewDetails = (item) => () => {
      console.log(item);
      toggleModal();
      return (
          <Modal item={item} /> //This is passing item into the Modal component
      )
  };
  return <div>
    {ViewDetails}  {/*This returns the function viewDetails*/}
  </div>;
}

export default Eexample;
```

For your Modal component:

```
function Modal({ item }) {  // with this distructuring, you can use the item inside the Modal component
        return (
            <Layout title="Dashboard" className="container-fluid">
               {<Modal open={modalStatus} onClose={() => setModalStatus(false)} />}
               <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                     <UserLinks />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-9">
                      <UserInfo />
                      {orders ? <PurchaseHistory /> : ""}
                  </div>
               </div>
            </Layout>
         )
      }
```

Or Consider using context API, it enables you to dispatch the item to your reducer.js file and pull it in your Modal component using StateProvider.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add more to @GODWIN GODWIN comment in regards context API, by providing a very simple example along with the React docs about [Context hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Generally in practice people tend to wrap providers at `App.js`, for the sake of simplicity I am going to wrap at `index.js` file.

**src/index.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App'
import { ModalProvider } from './context/ModalContext'

ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.querySelector('#root')
).render(
  /**
   * @dev Note everything inside ModalPrivder has access
   * to the values provided, such as open, setOpen
   */
  <ModalProvider>
    <App />
  </ModalProvider>
)
```

**src/context/ModalContext.jsx**

```js
import React, {useState, createContext, useContext } from 'react'

/**
 * @dev inside your createContext object you can pass in
 * default values that will be passed in value at provider
 */
export const ModalContext = createContext({
 open: false
})

/**
 * @dev your provider will enable you to access value all your
 * children components. NOTE it will not be able to access your
 * parent components.
 */
export function ModalProvider(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ open, setOpen }}>
      {props.children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**src/components/Modal.jsx**

```js
import { useContext } from 'react'

function Modal(props) {
  const { open, setOpen } = useContext(ModalContext)

  return (
    <>
      { open ? 
        (<div>
          <p>test</p>
          <>{props.children}</>
          <button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Close Close</button>
        </div>) : 
        (<button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Open Modal</button>)
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

**src/App.jsx**

```js
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Modal>
        <p> You see content here</p>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

I hope this give you a good direction on how to use React's context hook, please note that this is a very basic source code, to understand how `props.children` works and `context` hook.